# Specified cast is not valid within autocomplete source

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm facing System.InvalidCastException : Specified cast is not valid, I used child form and and exception throw from `ShowDialog()` I've search it and find a clue that this happen in child form and multithreading can solve it.
So, I tried to use multithreading but it isn't solved.
I tried to create new solution place the code and run it
but exception throw again. This is the code, I use click event to run method that construct aotucomplete to find where exactly exception is thrown.

```
private void AutoCompleteSource()
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection auto = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    auto.Add("text");
    textbox.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = auto;
}
```

exception is thrown from `textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = auto;`.
I tried to use multithreading again but can't fix it and System.InvalidOperationException was throw from
`textbox.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;`
this is code for multithreading.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread gg = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AutoCompleteSource));
    gg.Start();
}
```

So, I tried to delete `auto.Add("text");` and use an event to call only the method, finally it work fine...!

Is there anyone face this problem and can fix it?
I wonder if this is bug and I have to change textbox to combobox.

**Edit**
I've solved it by added `[STAThread]` to the top of static Main method.
I've said that I created new solution but I've never to click Window form application because I want to use only the code that I know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `BeginInvoke` when accessing `Controls` on a thread that is not the UI thread.

```
private void AutoCompleteSource()
{
    textbox.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection auto = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        auto.Add("text");
        textbox.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = auto;
    });
}
```